# Javascript: how do I make an image inside a variable clickable?

Tags: javascript

I am wondering how to make a variable set to new Image() clickable in Javascript.
I have a HTML5 canvas around the screen.

The useful code is here:

```
var btndone = new Image();
btndone.src = 'img/BtnDone.jpg';

btndone.onload = function(){
 LoadStartMenu()
}

function LoadStartMenu(){
 //Display BtnDone.jpg and make it clickable
}
```

The reason I am not using HTML and giving it an ID that way is because I can not find the   `context.drawImage(imagevariable,0,0);' (which gives the image a location) in HTML, and also because from what I know the image will display on the screen.

Comment: What do you want that click to do? Attach a link to it? Run a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just attach the `.onclick` function:

```
btndone.onclick = function() {
    console.log("You clicked the pic!");
}
```

Comment: To add to this, you could redirect it to a URL using window.location.href = 'http://some-url' in the handler.